# Integer and ArrayList issues

Tags: java, integer

This program is meant to prompt a user for address information.  Identify the address that would come first by zip code, and then print that address.

I'm having a couple of issues.  When I try to assign an `int` value to the apartment variable, I get an error.  Same thing with the zip code portion.  Once the minimum value is found, then I want to get the index of the minimum value so that I can print the same index value of each `arraylist`.

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me a good reference for this?  I think I'm just confusing a few things.

```
package newchapter7;
import java.util.*;
/**
*
* @author Crazy
*/
public class Address {


ArrayList<Integer> houses = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> streets = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> apts = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> zips = new ArrayList<>();
    int minValue;
    /**
    * Adds a house number to the address
    * @param house house number
    */
    public void addHouse(int house)
    {
         houses.add(house);   
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getHouse()
    {
        return houses;
    }
    /**
    * Adds a street name to the address
    * @param street street name
    */
    public void addStreet(String street)
    {
        streets.add(street);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getStreet()
    {
        return streets;
    }
    /**
    * constructor to add an apartment number that equals 0
    */
    public void addApt()
    {

    }
    /**
    * Adds an apartment number to the address
    * @param aptNbr apartment number
    */
    public void addApt(int aptNbr)
    {
        apts.add(aptNbr);
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getAptNbrs()
    {
        return apts;
    }
    /**
    * Adds a city to the address
    * @param city city
    */
    public void addCity(String city)
    {
        cities.add(city);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getCity()
    {
        return cities;
    }
    /**
    * Adds a state to the address
    * @param state state
    */
    public void addState(String state)
    {
        states.add(state);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getState()
    {
        return states;
    }
    /**
    * Adds a zip code to the address
    * @param zip zip code
    */
    public void addZip(int zip)
    {
        zips.add(zip);
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getZip()
    {
    return zips;
    }
    public int arrValue()
    {
        minValue = zips.indexOf(Collections.min(zips));
        return minValue;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package newchapter7;
import java.util.*;

public class NewChapter7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Address addy = new Address();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a house number: ");
        int house1 = in.nextInt();
        addy.houses.add(house1);
        System.out.print("Please enter the street name: ");
        String street1 = in.next();
        addy.streets.add(street1);
        System.out.print("Please enter an apartment number if applicable: ");
        int apartment;
        apartment = in.nextInt();
        addy.apts.add(apartment);
        if (apartment != 0)
        {
            addy.apts.add(apartment);
        }
        else 
        {
            addy.apts.add(0);
        }
        System.out.print("Please enter the city name: ");
        String city2 = in.nextLine();
        addy.cities.add(city2);
        System.out.print("Please enter the state name: ");
        String states2 = in.nextLine();
        addy.states.add(states2);
        System.out.print("Please enter the zip code: ");
        int zipC = in.nextInt();
        addy.zips.add(zipC);
    }


}

}
```

This is a homework assignment.  I think I've confused the material quite a bit and even if this works, I would like to learn a more efficient way to accomplish the same task.

Error

```
Please enter a house number: 772
Please enter the street name: Apple Drive
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
Please enter an apartment number if applicable:     
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at newchapter7.NewChapter7.main(NewChapter7.java:32)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)
```

Assignment:

Implement a class Address. An address has a house number, a street, an optional apartment number, a city, a state, and a postal code. Supply two constructors: one with an apartment number and one without. Supply a print method that prints the address with the street on one line and the city, state, and postal code on the next line. Supply a method public boolean comesBefore (Address other) that tests whether this address comes before another when the addresses are compared by postal code.

Comment: Requested to have this moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you have an error or exception, please show us the entire message.

Comment: The implementation of `public int arrValue()` looks weird to me. Why return the index? You're not calling this method though so perhaps it should be removed completely?

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added in the error code.  I'll try the changes you listed below as well.

Comment: @mbnew: consider posting the actual assignment requirements too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added the actual assignment description as well.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mbnew: OK, I was correct then -- you don't want any of those ArrayLists inside of the Address class.

Comment: Assignment says `Address` should have 'a house number, a street, an optional apartment number, a city, a state, and a postal code', whereas your class has `houses`,`streets`,`apts`,`cities`,`states`,`zips`. That should ring some bells. Also 'Supply a method public boolean comesBefore (Address other) that tests whether this address comes before another when the addresses are compared by postal code.' Note no mention of 'List's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Address class is mixed up and actually seems backwards to me. I think that you'd be much better off if it represented the state of a **single** address. If so, then it should not hold ArrayLists, but rather individual fields for a single house with getter and setter methods for each field, a constructor that accepts the field parameters, and perhaps a default constructor that accepts no parameters if desired.

Then if you need to work with many Addresses, you can create a single `ArrayList<Address>` for this.

Note that as an aside, I wouldn't use int for apartment number or zip code. While these look like numbers and comprise the digits of numbers, they don't behave as numbers. Use String instead.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>change</strike>

```
    String street1 = in.next();
    addy.streets.add(street1);
```

line to

```
    in.nextLine();
    String street1 = in.nextLine();
    addy.streets.add(street1);
```

and other `next()` to `nextLine()` also.

Ok the suggestion above is not working this is the full working code, but you have a *possible* logical error in this. Since it is homework you should be able to solve that. However...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a house number: ");
    int house1 = in.nextInt();
    addy.houses.add(house1);
    System.out.print("Please enter the street name: ");
    in.nextLine();
    String street1 = in.nextLine();
    addy.streets.add(street1);
    System.out.print("Please enter an apartment number if applicable: ");
    int apartment;
    apartment = in.nextInt();
    addy.apts.add(apartment);
    if (apartment != 0)
    {
        addy.apts.add(apartment);
    }
    else 
    {
        addy.apts.add(0);
    }
    System.out.print("Please enter the city name: ");
    in.nextLine();
    String city2 = in.nextLine();
    addy.cities.add(city2);
    System.out.print("Please enter the state name: ");
    String states2 = in.nextLine();
    addy.states.add(states2);
    System.out.print("Please enter the zip code: ");
    int zipC = in.nextInt();
    addy.zips.add(zipC);
}
```